# How can I change metadata in mp3

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, id3

I would like to add metadata to mp3 files in C/Objective-C (OS X).
I found several libraries (e.g. id3lib), but I have no clue on how to compile them.
Are there any tutorials on how you can do that? Is there any other framework for C/Objective-C to write ID3 tags to an MP3 file (song name, artist and coverart)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [id3lib Library Documentation](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/api/index.html).  It provides a quick tutorial.